# Android Не скачиваются 2/8 файлов

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Есть следующий метод скачивания картинки

```
try {
    url = new URL(cstr);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    String urlStr = cstr;
    String name = urlStr.substring(urlStr.lastIndexOf("images/")+7,urlStr.length());
    File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/.DmTest/images");
    sdPath.mkdirs();
    file = new File(sdPath,name);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
    downloadedSize = 0;
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    bufferLength = 0;
    while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
        publishProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
    }
    fos.close();
    inputStream.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    m_error = e;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    m_error = e;
}
```

Проблема в том, что 6/8 картинок в задаче этот метод сохраняет без проблем, а вот на две другие вылетает ошибка:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.DmTest/images/eng.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Ругается на строчку:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

В чем может быть причина такой ошибки, возникающей не всегда?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте проверку

```
if (file.exists()) {
    //продолжить
} else {
    //что-то пошло не так, повторить.
}
```

Проверьте, правильно ли все с путями, именами во всех случаях.